# How to Update the Existing Component in ReactJs?

Tags: reactjs

```
React.CreateElement('CustomComponent',{
       currSkill: 'Java'
});
```

Child:(It's an sample don't see spelling mistakes)

```
function CustomComponent(){
    base.call(this, props);
    this.currSkill = props.currSkill;
}

var base = Object.inherit(React.Component, CustomComponent);

CustomComponent.prototype.componentWillMount = function(){

}; 
CustomComponent.prototype.render = function(){
    if(this.currSkill == 'java'){
        return React.CreateElement('div',{},'Java');
    } else if(this.currSkill == '.net'){
        return React.CreateElement('span',{}, '.NET');
    }
}; 

return CustomComponent;
```

I am creating my custom Component like above, now after creating/rendering the Component, I want to change my currSkill property after some time.(i.e., get current Component and update the properties)

How to achieve this?

Comment: First off that won't work because the method is `.createElement`. But that's beyond the point, could you provide us with more info? How are you instantiating this component? What is its parent?

Comment: @ZekeDroid: Please check now. I have added more details.